# .HTACCESS and images

Tags: php, image, .htaccess

I have the following .HTACCESS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is then when I try and put an image in the webpage, or include a CSS or JS file in the `<head>` tag, it routes everything through to my index.php.  How can I prevent/work around this?

The aim is to have all traffic directed to my index, i.e. when the given URL is domain.com/shop or domain.com/signup then they would be taken to shop.php or signup.php respectively.  The problem is when including images and the like the routing through to index.php screws it over.  If I simply have an image tag:

`<img src="/img/foobar.jpg">` Then the image tries to load index.php with the attributes /img/foobar.jpg.  Which is not what I want to do.

The only solution I can think of is to hardode the URL in for every image. i.e.

`<img src="<?=HARDREF;?>/image.jpg">`

Comment: please be more descriptive on what you are hoping to achieve from this HTACCESS file. are you trying to redirect all the missing files to your index.php?

Comment: Is there an image folder where all images are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if file not exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# if dir not exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# avoid 404s of missing assets in our script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)$ [NC]

RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to exclude these filetypes:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|png|css|js)
```